# Javascript - Bolding part of buttons

Tags: javascript, button, keyword

Is there a way to bold only part of a button in javascript? My program generates buttons using javascript, and these button's values contain keywords tht the user searchers for. I'd like to the bold the keywords in the buttons without bolding any other words. I have searched all over the internet for a solution, but cannot find one. I know how to bold the text in the entire button, but I cannot figure out how to bold only the keywords in the button. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I know I could try using a different HTML entity other than a button, but I'd really like to use buttons for reasons that I don't hav enough space to go into. At any rate, if you're stumped, then for posterity's sake you could suggest which HTML entity you'd prefer me to use instead.

Comment: This is easy to do (see Jeffman's answer), but I'm curious about why you have buttons with so much text on them that it even makes sense to be thinking about bolding individual words that a user has entered.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the input element, use the button element:
works in all modern browsers.
as child nodes of button you can use any html, even images!

```
<button name="buttonName">hello <b>baby</b></button>
```

note that a button doesn's automatically submit a form. you have to attach the form's submit handler to the button like this (assumed it is the first form in the document):

```
<button name="buttonName" onclick="document.forms[0].submit();">hello <b>baby</b></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your keyword is dynamic, may I suggest using JS to specifically highlight the keyword in the button element? I have opted to use jQuery in my example. Let's say you want to highlight a keyword, say, "fox" in the button below:

```
<button>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</button>
```

We can use:

```
$(function() {
        // The keyword can be determined by user input or by other means
        var keyword = "fox",
            re = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");
        $("button").html($("button").html().replace(re, "<span>"+keyword+"</span>"));
});
```

The function above will wrap the keyword with the `<span>` element. Let's say we want to set the weight of the keyword to bold:

```
button span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/HuDKq/